# How would you optimize this jQuery-based navigation menu builder?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build a navigation menu based on certain types of content on a page. For instance I have a guitar lessons page where I have various exercise blocks.

An exercise appears on a page with a header as follows:

```
<h3 id="This-is-an-Exercise" class="exercise" topic="25447">This is an Exercise</h3>
```

Topics are already shown on the navigation sidebar and I add exercises via this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // get all exercises on page
    $(':header[class="exercise"]').each(function() {
        // add row to navigation menu under respective topic that contains the exercise
        var topicid = $(this).attr('topic');
        // now get topic div on left navigation sidebar        
        var topic = $('#' + topicid);
        var anchorid = $(this).attr('id');
        var namenoslashes = anchorid.replace(/-/g, " ");
        var html = "somehtml";
        // add the exercise
        topic.append(html);
    })

})
```

I have read  that jquery is often very inefficient if you don't carry out your selections in a well thought out way. Just that I don't know what is considered well thought out.

Is there anything in above code that clearly needs to be better optimized?

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: You might consider removing the jQuery entirely, it's not doing anything useful here that built-in DOM methods can't do just as easily. Storing arbitrary data in non-data attributes is a code smell, though - consider changing to data attributes

Comment: Thanks - made that value data-topic instead